# use local package with apt-get

Tags: linux, debian, apt, aptitude

I try to install package jruby with apt-get. One of the dependencies is package **ruby-thread-order** but apt-get fails to get that with

```
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/ruby-thread-order/ruby-thread-order_1.1.0-1_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: .....]
```

As a result, the installation fails.
In order to fix that, I have downloaded that deb-file and stored it locally.
However, installing it with dpkg seems not workable because of its dependencies.

Is it possible to make apt-get use that local package while downloading the rest of the packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that this situation can be solved like this:

- install the local package(s) prior to running apt-get and add the --force-depends flag. The package will be installed with warnings instead of errors for the missing dependencies: *dpkb --install --force-depends package.deb*
- install the dependencies with *apt --fix-broken install*
- now apt-get will take care of the rest: *apt-get install jruby*